# How to load the data in webview page by page in android

Tags: android, webview

I am using webview to display the html data.It is working fine if the data is less(less than 1 mb)..I am using following code

```
mDecryptDataWv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            DebugLog.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //showProgressDialog();
            DebugLog.i(TAG, "************onPageStarted **************");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            DebugLog.i(TAG, "************onPageFinished **************");

            if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    DebugLog.i(TAG, "mProgressDialog ::::::stopping");
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    mProgressDialog = null;

                }
            }
```

If the data is more then 1MB it is taking more time to complete the loading.so my intention is to load the data page by page upon user scrolling with progress dialog..Can anyone has idea?

Answer (score 0):

// I used this class and my code is working fime at my side please try this may be it will help you

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webview;
    private static final String TAG = "Main";
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;
    private TextView header_maintext;
    private TextView headeroptiontext;
    private RelativeLayout back;
    private String url_string="http://www.google.com";
    private String header_maintext_string="Your text";  

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         setContentView(R.layout.webview_layout);


        webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        header_maintext= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.header_maintext);
        header_maintext.setText(header_maintext_string);

        headeroptiontext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.headeroptiontext);
        headeroptiontext.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

          back = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.back_layout);
          back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(webview.canGoBack() == true)
                    {
                        webview.goBack();
                    }
                else
                    {
                        finish();
                    }
             }
        });

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(WebViewActivity.this, "My application", "Loading...");

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);
                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage(description);
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        return;
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        webview.loadUrl(url_string);


    }
    @Override

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(webview.canGoBack() == true){
                    webview.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```